# CP violation measurement

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, cp-violation

I have a question regarding the measurement of CP Violation in experiment. How is parity measured in an experiment? I know that in the direct measurement of CP violation we look at a particle process and then at an anti-particle process and try to see if there's a difference. But thats just charge conjugation (particle-antiparticle). How and where does partiy come into the experiment, for example at BaBar or Belle?

Comment: Are you familiar with Wu's experiment ([original paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.105.1413)) - measuring P violation in weak interactions? For CP violation, look at neutral mesons - $K^0$ and $B^0$, e.g. document page 6 (416) [here](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_12_2011.pdf).